# How to print all subsets of a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a basic case to deal with which is creating a dictionary and printing out it's subsets into a list.

I have tried itertools, chain and combinations;

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

dict = {1,2,3}

def powerset(iterable):
    s = set(dict)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

set(powerset("dict"))
```

this code gives:

```
{(), (1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (2,), (2, 3), (3,)}
```

I expect this:

```
[{}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 3}, {3}]
```

Comment: Why are you passing a sting to the `powerset()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are conflating [`dictionaries`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) with [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) . Second, it is strongly advisable to not name your variables same as python keywords or methods, as you have done here with `dict`.
Now, all the functions from itertools return an iteratable with `tuple`s as elements. So you will need to convert those back into sets.

```
[set(subset) for subset in powerset(dict)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this,

```
set(powerset("dict"))
```

to

```
>>> [set(value) for value in powerset("dict")]
```